# What security threats does the access_token for Facebook Graph API pose?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have made a custom ajax script to parse the JSON returned from the facebook graph API feed.

I have come to terms with the fact that the access token expires, so in order to get another one I can make a request to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECURITY
```

where APP_ID is the app id and APP_SECURITY is the app security values registered with my facebook app development account.

However I'm worried, because I'm making these requests via ajax, therefore anybody with basic chrome/firebug knowledge could access my app_id, app_security and access_token variables (from now on known as 'The Variables') held within my javascript file.

I am unsure as to what users can do this this kind of information?

Does the access token provide purely a read-only JSON output of my facebook page? Or can this information be used for more malicious purposes?

Now: before anybody replies saying that I should use php to get fetch the JSON and parse etc... I cannot, because the customer requirement is to use ajax, for the obvious asynchronous benefits.

If the variables pose no threat to my facebook account and can be only used for read only purposes, then I'll get on with my programming!

If however they must be kept secure... How can I securely pass the variables to javascript in order to keep the variable hidden?

PS. I already have pre-written php scripts to attain the variables. Just after a method to keep them secure when passing to the javascript (if necessary)

Thanks

Alex

Comment: Do NOT do this. They should not be publicly viewable. Even the docs tell you this. With your app id and secret, I could pretend to be your app and do whatever I wanted with the permissions I'd gain, and you'd be responsible. Basically, at no point should those variable ever get sent to the client.

Comment: Thankyou, I skimmed through the documentation but couldn't find anything. So If my access token expires, how do I get my php script to tell my javascript what the new access key is?

Comment: Oh im being such a newb... Its okay, got it covered. Thanks:)

Comment: I'd suggest having a proxy script which you can call via ajax that does the facebook requests itself. That way you can control who is requesting what and means you can keep all security credentials server-side only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Commented, Never Display APP_ID and APP_SECRET publicly.

Read [This](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/). You will find out a way to automatically find your access token using php.

Using this php file, make an ajax call to it, and it will return your new access token.